# jQuery AJAX JSON object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having some trouble with my AJAX request. 
The problem is with the JSON object named html.

AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url      : 'index',
    type     : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json', // Makes no difference
    data     : {
        method   : 'saveModule',
        html     : content
    }, 
    success : function(i){
        console.log(i);
    } 
})
```

I know it's about the html JSON object because if I remove it the request will succeed.

This is what it looks like with firebug's console.log();

***the object is stored within [ ], is that normal?***

```
[Object { name="Home", link="/home"}, Object { name="Work", link="/work", childs=[3]}, Object { name="Contact", link="/contact", childs=[2]}]
```

The childs are JSON objects as well.

Please help, it's driving me crazy!

The error I'm getting with the Web Console:

```
[11:58:47.215] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/mcms/htdocs/templates/resources/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 5"  data: no]
```

The **content var** is made from this:

```
 var content =  mcms.module.analyse(obj); // obj is a dom element, in this case a UL with sub ULs inside LIs
```

The function itself:

```
 analyse : function (that) {
        return $(that).children('li').map(function() {
            var b = {
                name: $(this).children('a').text(), 
                link: $(this).children('a').attr('href')
            };

            if ($(this).children('ul').size() > 0) {
                b.childs =  mcms.module.analyse($(this).children('ul'));
            } 
            return b;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `content` variable being set?

Comment: When you say "This is what is looks like with firebug's console.log()" are you talking about the output from the `console.log(i)` statement in your ajax success handler? If not, then what?

Comment: Yes that's it, but only the part that matters, the content var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I've found the problem and fix!***

The problem was that the .map() function returns an array around the JSON object. 
So I made a JSON object with a counter around the map to capture it and return it :)

Thanks for helping everyone!

```
analyse : function (that) {
        var b = {};
        var x = 0;
        $(that).children('li').map(function() {
            b[x] = {
                name: $(this).children('a').text(), 
                link: $(this).children('a').attr('href')
            };

            if ($(this).children('ul').size() > 0) {
                b[x].childs =  mcms.module.analyse($(this).children('ul'));
            } 
            x++;
        });
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the method parameter. If that is the method you are looking to call, you can as well include that in your URL, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your current call to `$.ajax` doesn't look exactly right. It should be something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url      : 'index',
    type     : 'POST',
    data     : <data to be sent>
    dataType : <Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)>
    success : function(i){
        console.log(i);
    } 
})
```

More info on the jQuery website: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**EDIT**

Ok, I see you corrected the call. This looks better now. Where does `content` come from and what's in it before it is converted into a JSON object?

**EDIT2**

Well, I think this answer should be of help to you: [Post Nested Object to Spring MVC controller using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900840/post-nested-object-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-json)

Comment: Added the info where I make the content var