# Angular JS POST request not sending data

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I am trying to send an JSON object to my webservice which is expecting JSON in the request data.
This my `POST` call from angularJS

```
$http({method: 'POST',
        url: 'update.htm',
        data: $.param($scope.cover),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function (data) {
    // handle
    });
```

Value for cover object

```
$scope.cover = {id:1, bean:{id:2}}
```

Iam getting `500 (InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'bean[id]' of bean class [BookBean]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'bean[id]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map;)`
In network, it is sending in this way

```
bean[id]:1
```

I think it should send like

```
bean.id:1
```

How to reslove this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want to use $.param if you are trying to send json data?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is getting to the server and is causing an error there. There's a possible duplicate question that's been answered here - [Post Nested Object to Spring MVC controller using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900840/post-nested-object-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-json)

Answer (score 0):

Try posting your data like:

```
$http({method: 'POST',
        url: 'update.htm',
        data: $scope.cover,
    }).success(function (data) {
    // handle
    });
```

Comment: In the server side I got null values