# Passing an array as a parameter of postdata in jqgrid edit form submit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am having an issue with the jqGrid. Here is the scenario.

1. I have a jqgrid with form edit set to true
2. On click of the submit button I need to pass additional parameters to the postData, one of which is an array itself.
3. I am using the onClickSubmit event to add values to the postdata like so

   postdata.param1="1";
   postdata.param2=
   [
   {
   "a":1,
   "b":2
   }
   ]

The issue is very similar to 
[Post Nested Object to Spring MVC controller using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900840/post-nested-object-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-json)

and i have implemented the same from my pojo class and the front end side as well.

But I still get the error.

Any suggestions?

Sriram

Comment: Have array which you use as parameter `param2` always one element? Are objects the elements of the array? Probably it would be enough to send `[1,2]` or `"1,2"` or `"a:1;b:2"` to the server? You can use `JSON.stringify( [ { "a":1, "b":2 } ])` instead of `[ { "a":1, "b":2 } ]`. All the options will **send** required data to the server and you can easy decode the data on the server side. There are sure many other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. there might be more elements in the array. I am stringifying the array and sending it. Now I am getting a 400(Bad request) from the server. At my wit's end here

Comment: I'm not a Spring MVC developer. So I can't help you on the server side. In any way you can have parameter of **string** type on the server side where you can get JSON data. You can use the corresponding API of Spring MVC to convert the string to object.

Comment: Thanks oleg. I will definitely take a look at the server side as well.