# POST and persist nested object to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900840/post-nested-object-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-json) and tried to fix it, but it still does not work.

Using: *Hibernate, Spring MVC*

I have a **@ManyToMany** relationship between the entities **Traveler** and **Address**.

If I create the **Traveler** and **Address** individually by their own controller, it works. But if I try to create a **Traveler** and the appropriate **Address** by the following controller, I get a 400 Bad request error:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/travelers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Traveler createTraveler(@RequestBody Traveler traveler, Address address) {
    logger.info("Start createTraveler");
    System.out.println("Received traveler: " + traveler.getLastName());
    travelerDAO.save(traveler);
    System.out.println("Received address: " + address.getStreet());
    addressDAO.save(address);
    logger.info("End createTraveler");
    return traveler;
}
```

Comment: There is only a single body, so you would only have a `Traveler` and with proper JPA configuration that would also store the `Address`. No need for 2 calls of 2 objects in your method signature.

Comment: Thanks. Your hint helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON payload is traveler object with nested addresses, spring should fill in collection of addresses for Traveler automatically (with help of Jackson).
Try it without address parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/travelers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Traveler createTraveler(@RequestBody Traveler traveler) {

   logger.info("Start createTraveler");
    System.out.println("Received traveler: " + traveler.getLastName());
    travelerDAO.save(traveler);
    System.out.println("Received addresses: " + traveler.getAddresses());
    //save addresses in loop
    return traveler;
```