# Object not bound from AJAX to Spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to pass data from javascript to spring controller using jquery ajax.

```
var inputParam = {
  name: "xxx",
  address: {
    city: "chicago",
    zip: "123456"
  }
};

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  url: "/myurl"+ $.param(inputparam),
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html"               
});
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getMyPage(  @ModelAttribute InputParams inputParam,HttpServletRequest request, Model model ) throws Exception{
        //my code
  }
```

**pojo**

```
class InputParams  
{
  private String name;
  private Address address;
  //getter setter
}

class Address 
{
  private String city;
  private String zip;
  //getter setter
}
```

But this is not working and i am getting error

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'address[city]' of bean class [InputParams ]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'address[city]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [City]

Comment: `$.param(inputparam)` doesn't create data that is compatible with `contentType :'application/json',`

Comment: You don't need to call `$.param` on the object you send. If you remove `contentType: 'application/json'` jQuery will encode it as `form-urlencoded` for you

Comment: so what should be the content type for this ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't understand what you mean. Remove contenttype or remove $.param

Comment: Remove both....

Comment: What's the expected content type  in the server for this request?

Comment: updated my question. I removed both content type and data. Still same error

Comment: What happens if you change the method signature in the controller as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913693/3301492)?

Comment: @Boris that require POST, which i don't want to do.